# Using R to fit: y ~ exp(-(x-x0)^a)

Tags: r, nls

I trying to fit y ~  exp(-(x-x0)^a) to this data but get the error:
 "Error in nlsModel(formula, mf, start, wts) : 
  singular gradient matrix at initial parameter estimates"

Do anybody have a tip?

```
x=c(0.612245,   0.47619,    0.857143,   0.535714,   0.535714)
y=c(0.865,  1.1374, 0.439,  0.8698, 0.8468)
m <- nls(y ~  exp(-(x-x0)^a), start=list(x0=-100,a=-100))
```

Comment: read this one: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/160552/why-is-nls-giving-me-singular-gradient-matrix-at-initial-parameter-estimates

Comment: The model looks very odd.  Are you sure you don't mean the Weibull model `y ~ exp(- exp(a * (log(x) - log(x0))))` ?

Comment: Model of my scientist.
I dont think I will correct him :)

Comment: I'll try the link :)
http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/160552/why-is-nls-giving-me-singular-gradient-matrix-at-initial-parameter-estimates